# How to define a system-wide alias for a Python script?

Tags: python, macos

I am working on Mac OS X and I have a Python script which is going to be called by other scripts and programs (Apple's launchd in particular). I could call it with

```
python /Users/xyz/long/absolute/path/to/script.py arg1 arg2
```

Since the location of the script might change, I want to decouple other scripts and the launchd configuration files from the actual location,  so that a call to the script looks like

```
script arg1 arg2
```

Defining an alias for Bash in $HOME/.bash_profile does not work, since launchd does not know about the alias.

What is the best way to define a "sytem-wide alias" or something equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually make a symbolic link and put it in /usr/bin (assuming /usr/bin is part of your PATH)

(In a terminal.  You may have to use *sudo ln -s* depending on the permissions.

```
ln -s /Users/xyz/long/absolute/path/to/script.py /usr/bin/script.py
```

If you take [Rory's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893543/how-to-define-a-system-wide-alias-for-a-python-script/893563#893563) and put the #!/usr/bin/python at the beginning of the script, you'll also need to make the script executable.

```
chmod a+x /Users/xyz/long/absolute/path/to/script.py
```

Comment: Good idea. I also put #! /usr/bin/python in the first line to make it executable. But I still get a

/usr/bin/script: Permission denied

if I call >script

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to chmod it manually?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do a chmod on it.  I edited with an example

Comment: As this is a "local" modification (not part of the core OS), I place the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`. Otherwise should work identically.

Answer (score 3):

As well as doing a symlink, you can put "#! /path/to/python" at the start of the script and make it executabe. Then you don't have to call it with "python /Users/big/long/path/script.py"

Comment: +1: Always put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the front of every script.